# 80s (or earlier) children's book series about a museum, time travel, and dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel, dinosaurs

In the mid-1980s, the Timberland Regional Library branch in downtown Olympia, Washington had a series of books about some children who discovered that a museum exhibit about dinosaurs could transport them back in time to see real dinosaurs.

Things I can remember:

- There were 3-4 books in the series
- About 3-4 children were involved
- The covers were a bright green, similar to the [qwantz.com](https://www.qwantz.com) T-Rex
- The books were slim, probably around 100 pages at most
- At one point the kids took a camera back in time with them, but the film was fogged and unusable when they returned

Answer (score 2):

The series is *[The Dinosaur Machines](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3984760-death-of-a-dinosaur)* by Eve Bunting. The book titles are below.

- *Day of the Dinosaur*
- *Escape from Tyrannosaurus*
- *The Dinosaur Trap*
- *Death of a Dinosaur*

Some of the covers can be see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5OdT.jpg).

Comment: Could you describe the plot of the books, to make it easier for us to tell whether this is likely to be a match or not? [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) provides some tips on how to write a good story ID answer.

Comment: Per ISFDB: "When one of them pulls the lever on the museum's dinosaur display, three children are transported back to a prehistoric dinosaur land."

Comment: Just noting here that I'm the original asker, but I could not figure out at this late date how to complete registration since I asked the question as a guest. This is 100% the series I was thinking of. Thank you, this has been bugging me for decades!

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial match for the [Magic Treehouse series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Tree_House) by Mary Pope Osborne, in which a brother (Jack) and sister (Annie) discover a magic treehouse, enchanted by Merlin (of King Arthur fame), which enables them to travel in time through a series of books within the treehouse. All they have to do is read/look at a part of the book and (IIRC) wish to go there, for them to be transported.

They have a whole series of adventures in both real and mystical times, but there is one book in particular "[Dinosaurs before Dark](https://www.magictreehouse.com/books/125113/dinosaurs-before-dark)", the very first in the series, in which they are transported to the time of the dinosaurs. There have been a few covers, of which one is below:

[image: Cover of "Dinosaurs before Dark", showing Jack riding a pterodactyl with Annie running on the grass below, and a volcano spewing in the background. The top of the cover is a dark green leaf background with the title and author.]

I don't believe that there is a camera involved, but the covers all include some green - brighter in some than others, and there are children involved, though usually just Annie and Jack.

Comment: I doubt this was it. The method of transportation doesn't match, and there are a *lot* more than 4 books in this series. I read a whole bunch of these when I was younger and I don't think it matches the OP's description.

Comment: Yup - that's why I have `partial match` in the first sentence.