# Children's Chapter Book, Possibly early 2000s?

Tags: story-identification, books

There's this children's Chapter Book that I've been looking for for absolutely ages. It involves four kids and they go through this like doorway or portal or something under the table in their little play house or treehouse.

They go on a whole bunch of adventures ant the end, they end up at this old fountain that somehow magically gets restored. I feel like it was a book about teamwork and friendship. At one point, one of the girls gets turned into a mermaid and they have to rhyme to turn her back I think? And they meet these friendly bears and one of them ends up getting choked out by vines.

I swear the title had something to do with the fountain, I might be wrong. But the cover had a fountain on it and I think the four kids as well. I was born in 2003 and I was reading this as a kid so it has to be early 2000s more than likely.

Comment: Was there time travel in the stories?

Comment: @basya I don't remember, there might've been?

Comment: Could it be "The Magic Treehouse", as described here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/231619/59154?  Though that sounds like only two kids as main characters...

Comment: @basya No, it's not Magic Treehouse